# one component not getting update when other component update from shared service with Observable Subject

Tags: angular

I have 2 component, *ProfileComponent* and *AvatarComponent* with no direct relation between them

Profile Component is used under user module ( *user.module.ts* ) and avatar component is being used in main module ( *app.module.ts* ) where I display user full name and profile picture on right top side.

My requirement is  Whenever user edit his/her profile ( first name or last name ) and hit save button. than avatar also getting updated with new first name and last name

I have followed this [Component Communication approach  from Angular Documentation](https://v4.angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

but my issue is that avatar is never being updated, even constructor is not being called from *avatar.component.ts*

angular version **4.3.4**

following is the relevant code

#### Profile.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html'
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    announce() {
        console.log('announce called: ');
        let username = 'alpha beta';
        this.userService.announceUser(username);
    }
    // when click on save button on edit profile button
    updateProfile(userProfile) {
        this.userService.updateUserDetail(userProfile).subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                this.announce();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

#### avatar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { UserService } from '../../../user/user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-avatar',
    templateUrl: `<div>
    <img #avatar [title]="fullName" alt="profile-picture">
    <span>{{fullName}}</span>
    </div>`
})
export class AvatarComponent implements OnDestroy {
    fullName: string;
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.getAvatar();
        this.subscription = userService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
            username => {
                console.log('subscribe it in constructor'); //never being called
                this.fullName = username;
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    getAvatar() {
        this.userService.getUserDetail().subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.fullName = `${data.firstName} ${data.lastName}`;
                this.userService.getProfilePicture().subscribe(
                    (image) => {
                        this.image.nativeElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

#### user.service.js

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

private missionAnnounceUsername = new Subject<string>();
missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnounceUsername.asObservable();
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

announceUser(user: string) {
    console.log('announceUser: ', user);
    this.missionAnnounceUsername.next(user);
}

getUserDetail() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`/user/profile`).map((res) => res.item);
}

updateUserDetail(data) {
    return this.httpClient.put(`/user/profile`, data);
}
```

}

Comment: Haven't sourced out the bug yet, everything looks pretty close, but I would suggest moving the logic out of the constructor in the avatar.component and into ngOnInit. http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/

Comment: Thank you for a valuable suggestion for the best practice. But I am right now looking for the solution. I have added HTML to `template` property which is not actually it is. the code is just for the sake of SO question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution from [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11618)

"Do not register any provider twice as this will create two independent instances."

I have registered *UserService* in main module *app.module.ts* whereas it should be in providers metadata of parent component of *avatar.component.ts* which is *layout.component.ts*

- removed `UserService` from *app.module.ts* *providers* metadata.
- add `UserService` from *layout.component.ts* *providers* metadata.

as `<app-avatar>` is used in layout.component.html

everything is working fine now.